# Are there any negative effects to editing my question many times?

Tags: support, questions, edits

Sometimes, I've had to edit my questions more than once in order to fix spelling mistakes, add appropriate tags, etc.

I was wondering what effect, if any, this repeated editing would have on my questions. Are there any negative consequences when a user makes a large number of edits to their own posts?

Comment: Related (mostly historical): *[Can we disable automatic community wiki conversion for answer edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203616/can-we-disable-automatic-community-wiki-conversion-for-answer-edits/228947#228947)* - *"The feature was never really about encouraging substantive edits as much as it was about prevent abuse. "*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no direct consequence to you for editing your posts multiple times. As long as you are making improvements to your post, then that's great; continue making edits as needed.

Obviously, we prefer that you try to "batch" your edits to minimize disruption, since each time you edit, the post is "bumped" (*i.e.*, it will show up as being "recently active"). So, try to fix as many spelling mistakes as you can at once, instead of submitting a different edit for each word. But if you miss one, and have to go back later to submit another edit fixing it, that's OK.

If you edit a post something like 20 times, an automatic flag is raised for moderator attention. This is completely invisible to you. What happens is that a moderator will review the flag and judge whether your edits are actually significant/substantial. If they think they are, then the flag is simply dismissed, and you never hear anything about it. If the moderator thinks you're just making trivial or nonsensical edits for the sole purpose of "bumping" your post, then the moderator will reach out to you privately and ask you to stop. They may also (or instead) temporarily lock the post from further edits.

The main thing you need to watch out for when editing *questions* that your edits do not invalidate existing answers. Adding more detail and explanation to a question is fine, but you don't want to change your question into something different after it has already been answered—that's unfair to the person who has taken the time to post an answer. You can't move the goal-posts after setting them up.

Comment: Thank's, english isn't my language. By "batch" you mean writing "Update" in my edit?, "bumped" is when the question shows itself as a new?

Comment: By "batch", I mean "group together into one". Try to make each edit significant, rather than making a bunch of tiny, trivial edits that are a few minutes apart. There is never any reason to write "Update" in the text of your question. All posts on Stack Overflow have a full revision history (like a source/version control system), so anyone can see exactly what was added in and when that edit was made. Saying stuff like "Edit" and "Update" just clutters things up and makes the post harder to read, so leave those out. "Bumped" means that your question shows up as "active".

Comment: Whenever a Q&A has new "activity", then it shows up on the "active" tab. This activity might be an edit to the question or one of the answers, or it might be a new answer being posted. This is distinct from a *new question*, which would also show up in the active tab.

Answer (score 0):

In two ways:

1. The original question might be harder to answer if it needs significant edits, making it less likely to get answered
2. editing your question will bump it to the active page, which may make it more visible.

Comment: By "active page" you mean that editing a question makes it appears as a new?

Comment: Not new just ["active"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Active). As in, this post has had recent activity.